# Problems using stoi

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a string that contains a subsequence of a number into an integer so  I can do mathematical operations on it. However, I keep getting:

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion
Abort trap: 6`

I used `cout` just before the call to stoi to see what was in item and I would get a number outputted.
For example,
If the `sequence` was 10, with n = 2, `cout << item;` would output:

```
0
1
10
```

As soon as I try to use `stoi` I get a program crash.

Here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (1 << n); ++i)
{
    string item;

    //Determining subsequence
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
          if ( i & (1 << j))
          {
             item.push_back(sequence.at(j));
          }
     }

cout << stoi(item) << endl; //error occurs here
}
```

Comment: What does the `string item` contain just before you call `stoi(item)`?

Comment: No useful answer can be given without at least the input used to trigger the error. A [mcve] please.

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you everything you need to know: `stoi` threw `std::invalid_argument` exception with message "no conversion" and that exception was not caught, so program terminates.

`std::stoi` can throw `std::invalid_argument` if you pass something that can't be converted to integer. Add `try-catch` to catch `std::exception` to avoid crash. Output your `item` to `cout` to examine the value you are trying to convert to integer.

You can also use debugger to execute your program step by step and examine different variables after each step. Trying to understand what's wrong just by looking at the code is useful for your brain but not very effective, unfortunately.